# Cannot connect to Compute Engine CentOS Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, centos6

I am new to Virtual Machines and CLI so please bear with me.

I have a **CentOS 6.5** running on Compute Engine.

I ran yum update (without creating a snapshot of the previous disk - Yes I am an idiot) and not I cannot connect to the machine using the ip address.

I tried the following steps.

Tried to connect through **Filezilla** - didn't work.
Tried through **Putty** - didn't work
Tried through the browser option given by the  **CE console** - didn't work.
I even tried creating a snapshot and starting up another **VM with the snapshot** - didn't work.

If anyone knows how I can get the files and folders out from the previous disk, I can start up a new VM and transfer everything again.

I do not have the latest database and this is important.

Please help!
Thanks
Warren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to recover is to delete your VM without deleting the disk, then create another VM **with its own boot disk**, attach and mount the original disk, and recover any data that you need from it.

First things first: on the VM instances page, click on the instance name that is currently running with that disk, and uncheck the box "Delete boot disk when instance is deleted". Then delete the instance.

Now, create a new instance with its own boot disk. To differentiate this new disk from the original boot disk:

- using a different OS (or version of the OS) for the new disk, e.g., if using Ubuntu, try a different version or use Debian; if using RHEL, try CentOS, or *vice versa*
- see which one is mounted at `/` — this should be the new disk

Mount the original disk as read-only and recover any information you need. Once you have a backup of your data, you can remount it with read-write access and try to fix it (but back up the data first!).

Comment: Hi Misha, 

I have followed the steps that you have listed. Can you please let me know how do I recover the information. A link with a tutorial would guide me. What I have understood is that I should now transfer the folders from the original disk to the new disk. This means transferring the files from the html folder in the original boot disk to the html folder in the new disk.

Comment: Hi, I ran fdisk -l and I got the below output. How would I know which is the boot disk from the 2 which are identical in size. ( I cut out some part since the comment was too long)

Disk /dev/sda: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              17      163825    10483712+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              17      163825    10483712+  83  Linux

Comment: Hi, Unable to mount the read only hard drive.

mount: block device /dev/sdb1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: Hi, Pasting in the command: sudo fdisk /dev/sdb -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
4 heads, 32 sectors/track, 163840 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 128 * 512 = 65536 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003ee67
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              17      163825    10483712+  83  Linux
[root@gym-test lib]# df /dev/sdb -T
Filesystem     Type 1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
-              -       292524   132    292392   1% /dev

Comment: I dont mind paying for the help if anyone has the knowledge of how to work around this.

Comment: @warren I have updated the answer to include how to differentiate the disks. Please add the additional information to your original question by editing it so that it's easier to format and read the command output. It's also unclear as to what the issue is: it sounds like you are able to attach the disk to the new VM and mount it; are you still having problems? Please update your question with your current status and feel free to delete these comments.

Comment: Hi Misha, I have solved it. I have written the description below.

Comment: @warren Great to hear that you've solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this problem thanks to Misha for sending me in the right direction.

The steps are below for anyone who has the same issue.

**Problem:**

While updating the Centos server using yum update, I was unable to connect back to the server.
I tried all possible combinations but no luck. This seems to be a known issue as there was some material on the Compute Engine site regarding this.

**Solution:**

I followed the steps as Misha suggested. I started up another VM with its own boot disk and then attached the original disk with read write access.

**Note:** I was unable to mount the disk as just read only.

The commands were

*mkdir /mnt/sdb1*

*mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1*

Once I mounted the VM, I copied the files from the html folder in the sdb1 disk to the html folder in the sda1(the new boot disk).

The database was a bit more challenging.

I tried quite a few times but copying the files from */dev/sdb1/var/lib/mysql* into the new disk mysql folder was not working.

I found some tutorials but nothing helped.

Finally I downloaded the files from within the */dev/sdb1/var/lib/mysql* and put them in my local windows mysql installation within the data folder.

Remember you have to download everything which includes the ib_logfile0 , ib_logfile1 and ibdata1 including the folder which has the *.frm files.

Then I opened localhost/phpmyadmin and voila... the files were there.

The rest was pretty simple... Exporting and uploading the SQL scripts back to the server.

This took me about 12 hours to figure out.

Thanks again Misha.